# Interupts Vs Poling a Device

Tags: c, windows-7, embedded

In my application a no. of devices (camera, A/D, D/A etc ) are communicating with a server.  I have two options for saving power consumptions in a device  as not all devices has to work always:

1- Do poling, i.e each device periodically keep on looking at a content of a file where it gets a value for wake or sleep. If it finds wake, then it wakes up and does its job.

In this case actually the device will be sleeping but the driver will be active and poling.

2- Using interrupts, I can awake a device when needed.

I am not able to decide which way to go and why. Can someone please enlighten me in this regard?

**Platform: Windows 7, 32 bit,  running on Intel Core2Duo**

Comment: Obviously interrupt-driven approach is better than polling, because (.. a lot of reasons ..). What platform is this for?

Comment: Windows 7, 32 bit, running on Intel Core2Duo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Polling is imprecise by its nature. The higher your target precision gets, the more wasteful the polling becomes. Ideally, you should consider polling only if you cannot do something with interrupts; otherwise, using an interrupt should be preferred.

One exception to this rule is if you would like to "throttle" something intentionally, for example, when you may get several events per second, but you would like to react to only one event per minute. In such cases you often use a combination of polling and interrupts, where an interrupt sets a flag, and polling does the real job, but only when the flag is set.

Answer (score 2):

If your devices are to be woken up periodically, I would go for the polling with the appropriate frequency (which is always easier to setup because it's just looking at a bit). If the waking events are asynchronous, I would rather go for an interrupt-driven architecture, despite the code and electronic overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on your hardware and software atchitecture and complexity of software. It is alwasy better to choose interrupt mechanism over polling.

As in polling your controller will be busy continuously polling the hardware to check if desired value is available.

While using interrupt mechanism will free the controller to perform other tasks, and when interrupt arises your ISR can perform task for specific need.